# CakePHP 3 debug_kit with subdirectory

Tags: php, css, cakephp-3.x

Developed locally and transfered everything on the Server now. It works fine, but the debugkit is not showing properly.

I can´t access the js,css etc. So I am just seeing an empty box with a not loaded cake picture. The data is written in the database (I am using the standard connection and just inserted the **panels** and **requests** tables.

So my guess is this causes all that. Or that my App is installed in a sub/sub directory.

**bootstrap.php**

```
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
    Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);
}
```

**app.php**
    'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),

```
'debug_kit' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'XXX-IP',
            //'port' => 'nonstandard_port_number',
            'username' => 'XXXDB',    // Your DB username here
            'password' => 'XXXPW',    // Your DB password here
            'database' => 'scdb',                
            'encoding' => 'utf8',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
            'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
            //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
        ]
```

The link its trying to process is:
https://www.example.com/sub/sub2/debug_kit/webroot/css/reset.css

*cake lies in the sub2 folder*

**htaccess from webroot**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub/webroot
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**htaccess from sub2**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @AD7six it´s just for debug_kit which is weird. The Version is in the title, but I added it in the tags too.

Comment: Note that your htaccess files do not match the rewrite rules for a [3.x application](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/webroot/.htaccess) - the presence of the `-d` rule suggests using  [rewrite rules from older versions of CakePHP](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/app/webroot/.htaccess) and the root htaccess file (sub2) in the question does not match [the root htaccess file from a 3.x app](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/.htaccess); which is one possible source of inconsistencies and confusion. Also note, you should always be using a production install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got it right now, stupid mistake - but I still wonder why it works on my other system :/

```
    RewriteBase /sub/sub2
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```

Before I had a slash infront of the `webroot/`

Thanks @AD7six for support. I appreciate it.

Comment: `Before I had a slash infront of the webroot/` don't write your htaccess files by hand :P - doing that makes your application different than a standard install (as it still is, because the other rules in the question don't match CakePHP's default rules) and means your problem is hidden (because the file you've put in the answer wasn't in the question...) and unique to your install. Glad you solved your problem, +1 for writing an answer.

Comment: Oh also: please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers,  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/243527.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 3.x does not automatically serve plugin assets unless the [asset filter is enabled](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html#built-in-filters). The simplest solution is to [symlink the plugin files to the webroot](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/deployment.html#symlink-assets):

```
bin/cake plugin assets symlink
```

Which is generally recommended for any plugin assets.

It should be noted that you should ***never* have debug kit accessible on a production install** as it is a rather obvious security concern.

Comment: AT the moment we can´t use the bin/cake, because or provider has to set the owner first. Is there a way without the console?

Of course, it won´t be "on" when we go in production mode. Even tho the user of this platform can barely copy and paste -.- and its htaccess protected

Why doesn´t this work for this project. Is it because of the subdirectory? I never had problems with the debug_kit

Comment: Just run it locally, and copy the result to your server - it is only creating a symlink. `Why doesn´t this work for this project.` at a guess this is your first 3.x project, earlier versions of CakePHP served plugin assets by default.

Comment: Okay,thanks.This just copied an directory Link to the plugin files. I just copied the debug_kit/css,js,img files and directories into webroot. But still nothing.

Comment: `https://www.example.com/sub/sub2/debug_kit/webroot/css/reset.css` this url, which is in the question, is wrong - if it's requesting that url, in addition to your first question/problem there's a setup problem. the url should be `https://www.example.com/sub/sub2/debug_kit/css/reset.css`

Comment: `https://www.example.com/debug_kit/webroot/js/debug_kit.js` - Yes, I know it´s hard from outside to get any solution. But any guesses? Everything else works, which is totally weird. One sec. I fixed that in app.php 'App' => 
'cssBaseUrl' => 'webroot/css/',
        'jsBaseUrl' => 'webroot/js/',

Comment: Well If I change it, it works! Buuuut, the the normal css and js etc. won´t load :/